# Cannot resolve div ID inside JS using Vaadin

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin14

New WEB person here.   Been doing JAVA for 20 years, and this is 1st time in the web pool.   Anyway, I am using Vaadin and like it very much.   I am using the *subwindow* component (user contrib) to give me a workspace in the browser where I am opening up other windows.   In one of these windows, I am trying to attach a javascript component.      I have already verified the component runs in a plain page, but when I try to attach in the window in the workspace, it cannot find the Div-ID.    I have tried many, many versions.   Even executing the script AFTER the window is displayed using a simple button.
If I use the dev tools in Chrome, I can dig down and find the window/Div space and I see the ID is correctly set.
If there something I must do in JS to see an ID that is nested??

In the JS I am just using: document.getElementById(myid)... ect...

Thanks!

Thank you for all that responded.
I ended up passing the Div element into the javascript when it was started.   Worked like a charm.   Now to make resize work..

Comment: Is the Div you are looking for in shadow DOM, if yes then document.getElementById(myid) will not find it. Do you need to find this Div in Java or JavaScript side?

Comment: What version of vaadin are you using? Can you please share some minimal example, that shows your problem? Or at least the relevant code parts.

Comment: I see it in the shadow DOM (whatever that is)....   Using Vaadin 14.    Due to network, I cannot add code.  :<(

Comment: Seems to be a shadowRoot inside a shadowRoot

Comment: In your case you should modify your subwindow component (assuming that has the Div you are looking for). In Java you can use Id annotation to inject that Div as field in subwindow class and then create getter for that.

Comment: Without the code, this will be pure guess work. So here is my guess: you have a div in somewhere in your application code and now you try to tack on some JS.  You will have an uphill battle with that, since shadow DOM is meant to isolate webcomponents. You will have an easier time turning your "javascript component" into a proper webcomponent to use in vaadin.

Comment: Provide details as edits to your Question, not as Comments.